# Easiest ways to generate graphs from Python?

Tags: python, graph, visualization, google-visualization

I'm using Python to process CSV files filled with data that I want to run calculations on, and then graph.  I'm looking for a library to use that I can send processed CSV information to, or a dict of some sort, and then choose different graphing styles with.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Did you ever choose a plotting library?

Answer (score 10):

I'm personally using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) and am very happy with it.

Answer (score 7):

[Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) and [Gnuplot.py](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) are popular choices. I've used both.

Answer (score 4):

For client-side charts [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) or [Google Charts Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/).

Comment: Google Charts Tools [link](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools), as recommended by you, is a great option. I've tested it out and it'c ool.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) for about 3 years now to plot experimental data.  Before I was using Excel and that was just a pain.  I've been happy with matplotlib ever since.  It's great and very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

There is [pychart](http://home.gna.org/pychart/) or [PyCha](http://bitbucket.org/lgs/pycha/wiki/Home), both of which I have not used but have been considering myself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of graph you want,
most of the time, i'm using matplotlib but sometimes[pydot](http://dkbza.org/pydot/pydot.html) is good.
The various layout algorithms are good for me when dealing with huge graphs