# Plot functions in Python

Tags: python

I am required to use Python for engineering project. Need to create many graphs, including surface plots. In the past I used Matlab for  plotting and really liked it. I was wandering if there is a module/package/extension which bring similar capability into Python.

To be more specific, I need piloting for 2 different reasons.

1. To understand how functions behave. Something quick and dirty would do it.
2. Publication/presentation. Ability to add labels, legend, grid, customise colour, axis properties etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python library to plot graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596684/python-library-to-plot-graph)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate. I vote to lock my own question :)

Comment: Yes. There are a bunch of dups of this question. [Here's another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523689/easiest-ways-to-generate-graphs-from-python/2523722#2523722), and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120542/what-is-the-best-plotting-library-for-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), it's pretty extensive and has a [shell similar to MATLAB / Mathematica](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect [matplotlib.pyplot](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) would be right up your alley.